# Facing issues while trying to access a file of type docx stored in aws-s3 bucket with the help of python-docx

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-docx

I have a docx file at my aws-s3 bucket. I need to read it use python-docx. 
I write this:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('https://my-first-backup-bucket-v1.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/New+Proposed+Quote.docx')
```

then, have error.. 
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'https://my-first-backup-bucket-v1.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/New+Proposed+Quote.docx'

why?

when I tried to access the same file from browser it is opening successfully. for testing purpose I created this file with public access anyone can test this, can anyone please help on this?

Comment: What makes you think that `Document()` accepts a URL? Do you have a reference to such usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Document objects — python-docx 0.8.10 documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#document-constructor):

> `docx.Document(docx=None)`
>
> Return a Document object loaded from docx, where docx can be either a path to a .docx file (a string) or a file-like object. If docx is missing or None, the built-in default document “template” is loaded.

It is saying that the supplied filename should point to a **local file**. It does not say that a URL is accepted.

Therefore, you should download the file from Amazon S3, then point to it on the local file system.

Comment: Thanks for the info . But if we want to handle in aws lamda function (which is a server-less service) how can we download it? any reference

Comment: You can use [`download_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) in the AWS SDK for Python (boto3) to download a file to `/tmp/`. Be sure to delete it when you have finished using it, since there is only 500MB of storage space provided.